# Determine their domain and graph the domains

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Given the following functions, determine their domain and graph the domains:

a) $ f (x, y) = \sqrt {| x | - | y |} $

---

b) $ f (x, y) = \log (1- 4x ^ 2 - \frac {x ^ 2} {9}) $

---

c) $ f (x, y) = \sqrt {(x-3) \cdot (y-2)} $

---

d) $ f (x, y) = \sqrt {\frac {4- x ^ 2-y ^ 2} {x ^ 2 + y ^ 2-1}} $

---

Is there a mechanical way for me to resolve these issues? It is really a doubt. Is there a program that makes me better understand, or do I need to do it manually?

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you need to know is that anything inside a square root is non-negative, so for the first case for example, you should have $|x| \geq |y|$. Can you graph this?

C) and D) require similar analysis.

For the case B), you need to know that anything inside a logarithm is positive. That is, for $y= \log x$, the domain of $x$ is greater than $0$. Can you proceed ahead?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Long time no see, man. I messed up, got 4k rank , so I chose BITS PILANI (goa) CSE... what about you?

Comment: Ah, I saw that you have chosen chemical at IITM. It's nice to study at old IITs, but I didn't want lower branches, so opted out of it. Plus, I'm a general category male so I have not got any reservation benifits.

Comment: BITS is really good too but i dont like computer science so didnt even apply anyway  lets keep in touch

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Oh, 2k rank is nice. I think that eng physics cutoff of IITD is around 2k only. Sure, let's keep in touch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131197/discussion-between-albus-dumbledore-and-vilakshan-gupta).

Comment: Hey ,how are u ?

Comment: remember old samyak Jha we both are right now wing mates in iitb !!

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I'm fine :) . Nice man! So you're in IITB Chem now, cool! I remember you wanted to go to IITM last time we interacted. So how's college life? Studies, social life? Enjoying?

Comment: ya i got changed to iitb chemE in 6th round.Studies is going well,but socially i am still sitting in a orner and being an introvert lol.Trying to change but its hard to do so when one has lived 18 years of solid isolation

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I understand, but just try to make as many friends as you can because they're the most important thing in your college life.  So is your first year over? And you still active on MSE ?

Comment: ya first yr over ,not really active ,perhaps  just answering one question per month,but visiting site regularly.How are u finding CS? i was thinking of branch change but then decided against it

Comment: Oh. CS courses start from second year, so I don't really know much about it. Vacations are going on. Second year starts from september...